# What does `nlme`'s `intervals()` return?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

In the output from the code below, is 25.59 the residual *standard deviation*, or some type of *standard error*? The [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/nlme.pdf) say s.d., but the printed output says s.e.

```
library("lme4") # contains the sleepstudy data
library("nlme")
sleepstudy$DaysC <- with(sleepstudy, Days - mean(Days)) # centering

lme2a   <- lme(Reaction ~ DaysC, 
               random=reStruct(~DaysC|Subject, pdClass="pdDiag"),
               data=sleepstudy) 
intervals(lme2a)$sigma
```